# Load different themes by user in Community

Tags: community, custom-theme-layout

I have a community site. I have two different themes. Can I load different themes at runtime? For some users, I want to show the `Theme1`, and for others, I want to show 'Theme2'.

The whole thing is, I have a particular client. I want to provide completely different looks and feels to the users. The theme will be aligned with the branding of that client. Any other options?

Limitations:

- I can not use two different community sites.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried the example from [Detecting UI Theme Using Apex Utility Methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/isv/2016/04/introducing-ui-theme-detection-for-lightning-experience.html/)?

Comment: You might want to try "Page Variations" and assign them to specific audiences